# Proof of Łoś-Tarski theorem: explanation of the obtained contradiction

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, model-theory

I'm going through the following document about model theory: [https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/modelthmoeder.pdf](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Eooste110/syllabi/modelthmoeder.pdf) in which a proof of the Łoś-Tarski preservation theorem is given.
I understand most of it, but for the left to right implication I don't get where the contradiction comes from. I.e., why does $\mathfrak{B}\models\forall x_1...\forall x_n \neg \phi(x_1,...,x_n)$ contradict with $\phi(b_1,...,b_n)$ being an element of $\Delta_{\mathfrak{B}}$?

The particular part (page 19):
[image]

An explanation is very much appreciated!

Comment: See page 5 def of *diagram*: $\Delta_B$ is the colelction of atomic sentences (and their negation) that are true in $B$.

Comment: But what contradicts what here?

Comment: $B \vDash \forall x_i \lnot \phi(x_i)$ implies $B \vDash \lnot \phi(b_i)$ because - I presume - the $b_i$s are objects of $B$. But to say that $\phi(b_i)$ is in $\Delta_B$ means, by def, that $B \vDash \phi (b_i)$

Answer (score 4):

If $\phi(b_1,\dots,b_n)\in \Delta_{\mathfrak{B}}$, then $\mathfrak{B}\models \phi(b_1,\dots,b_n)$.

If $\mathfrak{B}\models \forall x_1\cdots \forall x_n\lnot\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, then (instantiating each variable $x_i$ by the element $b_i$ in $\mathfrak{B}$),  $\mathfrak{B}\models \lnot \phi(b_1,\dots,b_n)$, which means $\mathfrak{B}\not\models \phi(b_1,\dots,b_n)$.

$\mathfrak{B}\models \phi(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ and $\mathfrak{B}\not\models \phi(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ are contradictory.